Display Confusion of pointer in c
I'm not able to understand the proper working of my C code.
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[]={10,11,-1,56,67,5,4};
    int *p,*q;
    p=a;
    printf("%d %d %d",(*p)++,*p++,*++p);
}

Output: -1 11 11
Why its not :11 11 -1?
Associativity of Post Increment is left to right and and Pre Increment having Right to lift but I think it should operate left to right only cause Post one has higher increment.
